# How do I move / to my new SSD

Tags: boot, ssd

I built a computer and loaded ubuntu 14.04 onto my HDD.  I recently got a SSD and wanted to put / and /home on the ssd and all other storage on the HDD.  How would I go about this process.

Comment: What do you mean by "all other storage"? "/" Is already including your whole system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are rather new to Linux world, I would recommend reinstalling the system to get the most out of your SSD and HDD.

Bear in mind,  that ''**/** '' is the place where the system files and directories are located. Applications are installed inside this directory.

'' **/ home**'' is the place where your personal data (documents, images, video, configuration files, etc.) are.

While installing Ubuntu,

1. mount ''/'' directory on your SSD and
2. ''/home'' on HDD. Thus programs will run faster and you will have more space for keeping data.
   (  *I think your HDD is bigger than SSD, right?* )

See here for more info: 
 [Manual disk partitioning guide](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/)

You can resize partitions and move them without reinstalling the system, also. You should use Gparted software for this purpose.

See here: [HTG Site: Resize partitions](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/)